# Deactivate all conda environments

Tags: conda

When a conda environment is activated, conda remembers the previously activated environments. For example, if no environment is activated, calling `conda activate foo` and then `conda deactivate` results in no environment being active. However, calling `conda activate foo`, and then `conda activate bar`, and then `conda deactivate` results in the "foo" environment being active. Conda puts each environment on a stack as it is activated and deactivating merely pops one item off the stack.

How do I deactivate all conda environments when using the bash version of conda?

For example, if I had a script that rebuilt an environment, it would need to ensure that that environment is not currently active, so it should deactivate all environments. I could just stick ten or so `conda deactivate`s at the top of the script and that would probably be enough, but I am looking for something less janky.

Answer (score 11):

The depth of the conda environment stack is stored in the environment variable `CONDA_SHLVL`. Running `conda deactivate` that many times should deactivate all environments.

```sh
for i in $(seq ${CONDA_SHLVL}); do
    conda deactivate
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if any direct route exists, `conda deactivate` does not have any documented command line arguments and there is no other command that `conda --help` reports on my system that might help here.

One way for you, as you are in `bash` might be to abuse the fact that conda sets `CONDA_PREFIX` to the path of the currently active env. Therefore you could deactivate until that variable is no longer set:

```
while [ ! -z $CONDA_PREFIX ]; do conda deactivate; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The *activation* of a conda environment means that the environment you *activate* is the environment used by the application. So, you always have an active environment in conda (when you deactivate, another environment is activated).

A possible option for you is activating the conda *base* (default) environment, like `conda activate base` (or any other environment you prefer to activate explicitly). You can also remove the environments you do not want.

This is a good post on the subject: https://towardsdatascience.com/manage-your-python-virtual-environment-with-conda-a0d2934d5195