# Switch ad-hoc between distro and anaconda python versions

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

I have installed `anaconda` on Ubuntu 20.04 (`conda --version` says `conda 22.9.0`).

Now the global python version (`which python`) is controlled by `anaconda` since it
installs its init code in `.bashrc`:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/user/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/user/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/user/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

**For testing purposes I sometimes want to use the standard distro python version and packages.**

How can an easily switch between `anaconda` and the distro python version?

My current work-around is to use `conda init --no-user` or commenting the above conda init script in `.bash.rc` to achieve this (requires opening a new shell)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conda installation comes with a default environment, often named `base`. That's what you see when typing `which python`: it links to the conda version of python.

As any other conda virtual environment, you can deactivate this base environment through `conda deactivate`.

If you do not want this base environment to be activated when opening a new terminal, you can use `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`.
You could then activate this default environment when needed, through `conda activate base`.

Comment: If I comment all conda init lines in `.bashrc` then the `conda` command is no longer in the path so that I cannot activate `conda activate base` again.

Comment: then as a workaround you can add `conda deactivate` at the end of your `.bashrc`

Comment: I think then it is easier to comment all conda init lines in `.bashrc` to activate the distro python again (like I do ATM)

Comment: I humbly disagree: as you said, you then can't use conda; or have to uncomment all lines and open a new terminal or `source .bashrc` to make it work. easier and cleaner to deactivate the base environment when needed !

Comment: OK, I will give it a try (AFAIR deactivating the base env does **not** activate the distro python by default but I will double check). BTW mentioning `source`: I could use separate a script to switch between anaconda and distro python (if I find out how)...

Comment: THX for pointing me to the right direction, `conda deactivate` is the way to go. It has only the bad habit to keep a stack of all activated envs (I have several envs) so I have to call `conda deactivate` repeatedly until `conda env list` shows no more `*` after any env name. Then `which python` finds the distro python version again. So my problem was to call `conda deactivate` only once ;-)

Comment: For details about the stacked conda env activations see https://stackoverflow.com/q/68441393 (I am just missing a `conda deactivate all` command now ;-)

Comment: This is half bad advice. Either use the `conda deactivate` command for *ad hoc* deactivation, or set `conda config --set auto_activate_base false` (once at the commandline) to configure Conda to not auto-activate **base**. One should not be manipulating the Conda code in the shell initialization file and adding `conda deactivate` to `.bashrc` is wasting CPU cycles activating then deactivating.

Comment: @merv THX! This is worth an answer :-)

Comment: @R Yoda: "stacking" conda env is usually a bad practice and can lead to unexpected behaviour and errors when installing new packages. I learned that the hard way :'-)

Comment: @merv I agree with the comment part, I have updated my answer accordingly. While your solution is the proper way to go, the argument of wasting CPU cycles is imho not really an issue !